# Package hierarchy of large scale projects

Tags: go

I want to work on a large scale project. For the sake of common programming paradigms, I want to divide my project into packages. An example is as follows:

```
project/
    domain/
    utils/
    system/
```

The Go packaging system seems to be not appropriate for this kind of packaging. Each package is assumed to be standalone packages. But when dealing with a large scale project, one may have to use packages somehow dependent to each other. There are several reasons to build a hierarchy like this:

- Loosely coupled code
- Logical separation of code base
- Managing whole project in a single VCS repository

So, is this possible in Go or should I just adapt myself to package everything under `GOPATH`? In this case, I have to create a repository for each package and there will be packages that importable from irrelevant packages but meaningless mechanic for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each package (besides *main*) in Go behaves like a library.

You should compose your packages as you would produce a library. It looks to be very simple and valid approach - it follows main Go principles. A library should know everything about itself.

> But when dealing with a large scale project, one may have to use packages somehow dependent to each other.

This looks like a spot of problems. Why you will like to have two packages (`a` and `b`) which depend on themselves (`a` requires `b` and `b` requires `a`) - it's against one of the Go principles (circular dependency). If you anyhow think about this usage, then you should merge those packages.

If you are still unsure how to compose packages - then look at *Go* standard library. Good example might by [http package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/).

In our project we want to separate application types (model) into separate package, so we can use them in other applications of a project. You need to think which part of you project you want to use as an application, and which as a library/driver.

> Loosely coupled code

Practically, there is no limit in files number in the same package (directory).
*[update]* Package is a bunch of files within the same directory. Packages / directories can be nested.

> Managing whole project in a single VSC repository

There is nothing which may stop you to keep all libraries from the project in a single repository. Go std packages (there are dozens of them) are in a single repository.

*[update]* Also you need to understand difference between packages and how *go get* resolves / fetch them. [go get](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) is a **tool** which interprets `import` paths and handles ones with *supported* prefix (eg: github, bitbucket .... - you can read about them in go get docs). So if a packages starts with *github/user/name* it clones whole repository locally using *HTTPS*.

So for example I have two packages in the same repository:

- "github.com/scale-it/go-web"
- "github.com/scale-it/go-web/handlers"

And `go get` understand them and clone only once (under *$GOPATH/src* directory)

Comment: If you find yourself frustrated by circular dependencies between *a* and *b*, it often means there should be a common *c* they should both refer to instead.

Comment: Is there any example of single VCS repository of multiple packages in Git? Only thing I see is different packages under `GOPATH` under different directories, and as far as I know Git is used for one root directory. Is there any example beyond my knowledge you can provide?

Comment: @Rick-777 - the whole point about circular dependency is that they are wrong, and it's good that go compiler prohibits them (as most of other interpreters/compilers).

Comment: @mtyurt - I don't know if I understand your question correctly. `go get` tool handle public VCS services and go packages can be nested. I've updated my answer for that (please look at paragraphs with *[update]*)

Comment: @RobertZaremba totally agree - circular dependencies are neither necessary nor useful There's also a direct equivalent in the channel communication graph: circular dependencies usually lead to deadlocks; a DAG is provably deadlock-free (see J.Martin & P.H.Welch 1997 http://kar.kent.ac.uk/21490/)